# Adding SSL to Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-boot

With the command

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keystore KeyStore.jks -keysize 2048
```

i generated keystore.
Next, I placed the generated file in `resource` and I have added to the configuration

```
#server
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:KeyStore.jks
    key-store-password: JonkiPro
    key-password: JonkiPro
```

(I set the same passwords when generating the file)

But the application has stopped working and the server does not respond. The program compiles correctly but does not find the server
https://zapodaj.net/e71e6875b721b.png.html

Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

define the port of the server `server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=secret
server.ssl.key-password=another-secret`

> the application will no longer support plain HTTP connector at port 8080. Spring Boot doesn’t support the configuration of both an HTTP connector and an HTTPS connector via application.properties

[documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html)

Comment: this mean that 8449 port is in use in your system you can terminate any process in this port if you use windows [this link will help ][(http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2015/04/16/windows-kill-process-by-port-number)